# Visual Studio 2015 Stuck Initializing Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Professional.  Every time I open my solution and either click/open on the Unit Test project within the solution or any of the files within the Unit Test project, I get a popup window that states "Initializing Templates...".

Visual Studio then becomes unresponsive and the mouse cursor turns into a spinner.  Sometimes it finishes (after several LONG minutes) or I just get frustrated and kill devenv.exe and try to avoid clicking on the project.  I then use VS2013 if I need to make changes within that project.

I have tried repairing Visual Studio 2015.  I have uninstalled it (and all 3rd party add-ons) and reinstalled it.  Nothing seems to work.  I would really like to use VS2015 but this is kind of a deal breaker.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**
I tried opening another solution and when I went to the Unit Test project within it, I got the same popup/freezing.

Also, I just opened Visual Studio and tried to create a new project.  Same popup and now its frozen.

**EDIT 2**
Seems running the program as Administrator is causing the issue.  If I run Visual Studio 2015 normally, it eventually "initializes the templates" (after about 15 seconds).  Run VS2015 as administrator, and it just gets stuck "initializing templates".  Seems counter-intuitive.

I would still like to have this problem resolved.  I do have to run VS2015 occasionally as an administrator.

Comment: The only thing you can do is resetting visual studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Running `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` fixed the issue for me. It took about 7 minutes to run, though, so be patient.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try when I get home.

Comment: @ELMOJO did this solution solve your problem ? I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me.  I tried it from the command line and from the start menu search box both as an administrator.  I still get "Initializing Templates" when I start VS2015 with administrator privileges.  It eventually loads the templates but it takes a while.  I would still love to have this resolved.

Comment: I had the same problem but it only took 30 seconds or less

Comment: you're my hero. This worked for me, had to open CMD with admin priv (win10)

Comment: Thanks. It also worked for me :)  I've had this problem since I had installed two different versions of Telerik Reporting in parallel. I had to run cmd w/ admin privs. It took about 10 minutes to run.  (VS2013 update 4, Win8.1)

Comment: Amazing! I ran it from the Developer Console as Administrator.  It took 7 minutes just like you said and when it finished, Visual Studio 2015 now starts in less than 5 seconds!  (Note: I always have it open without auto-opening a Solution.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I even tried the solution given above by Collin, but it showed me the error message "The operation could not be completed. Access is denied"
[image]

Following the steps below solved my issue-
Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall a program -> Search for Microsoft Visual Studio (Mine was Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013) -> double click and select Repair button. This will solve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution

```
1. Open existing project from .sln file
2. Close the internet connection
3. Right click on main solution and click add new project
```

Follow above step it will work.